# Javascript canvas lineTo, wanting to stop after certain distance

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am working on a separate project where I'm trying to draw a line from a turret, to an enemy. But I want the line to stay within the boundaries of the turret, and not extend all the way to the enemy. A smaller example that I have made can be found below in the code snippet.

Please be thorough in your answers, because I'm definitely no expert. It'd be much appreciated! Thanks.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

var turret = {x:20, y:20, w:20, h:20};

var randomBox = {x:30+Math.random() * 300, y:30+Math.random() * 300, w:40, h:40};

c.fillStyle = "red";
c.fillRect(turret.x, turret.y, turret.w, turret.h);

c.fillStyle = "yellow";
c.fillRect(randomBox.x, randomBox.y, randomBox.w, randomBox.h);


c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(turret.x + (turret.w/2), turret.y + (turret.h/2));
c.lineTo(randomBox.x, randomBox.y);
c.stroke();
```

```css
#canvas {
  background-color: #eee;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=500></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Vector maths.

A line can be thought of as a coordinate and a vector, the vector describes the direction and distance from the start coordinate to the end point. When you describe a line by its endpoints you are using 2 coordinates. Usually we call a line with a start and end as a line segment, as opposed to a line which is actually infinitely long.

The line segment as coordinates

```
 var x1 = 100;
 var y1 = 100;
 var x2 = 300;
 var y2 = 400;
```

#### Line segment's vector

To get the vector component of a line you simple subtract the start point from the end point. A vector is a line segment of sorts that always has its start point at the coordinates 0,0.

```
 var vx = x2 - x1;  // v for vector
 var vy = y2 - y1;
```

#### Magnitude or length

All vectors have a magnitude (or length) which is always positive by virtue of how the length is calculated. The x,and y components of the vector make up the two shorter side of a triangle and the line along the vector is the longest line, the hypotenuse.

We use pythagoras to calculate the vectors magnitude.

```
var mag = Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy); // mag for magnitude
```

#### Normalise vector

In many situations regarding lines (like in this case) we are not so much interested in the length of the line but rather just the direction. To make calculation easy we like to use a special form of the vector called a unit vector. This is a vector that is precisely 1 unit long (in our case 1 the unit is a pixel)

The unit vector has many properties that are very useful when doing geometry.

The process of creating a unit vector is called normalising. It is just done by dividing the x,y parts of the vector by its total length (as calculated above)

```
// normalise vector
var nx = vx / mag;  // n for normal
var ny = vy / mag;
```

#### Scaling the normal

Now that you have the unit vector representing the direction of the line it is easy to find a point a fixed distance from the start. Like on the number line if you want a point 10 units from say 5 you add 10 to 5. But its is also the same as 10 "units" to 5 or `10 * 1 + 5`. In Geometry the unit is the unit vector.

So if we want the point 10 units (pixels) from the start we multiply both components of the unit vector by 10 and add them to the start coordinate.

```
var endX = x1 + nx * 10;
var endY = y1 + ny * 10;
```

Now endX,endY is 10 pixels away from the line start.

---

#### Vector math.

As you can see having the unit vector makes it easy to get any point any distance from the start point.

All vector libraries include the above operations for vectors and coordinates. We call a set of two coordinates (x,y) a 2D vector `vec` and we have operations like `add()`, `sub()`, `multiply()`, `divide()`, `magnitude()`, `normalise()`, and a few equally handy operations like `cross()` and `dot()` but that is out of scope for this question for now.

If you are interested in writing games I strongly suggest that you write you own small 2D vector library, it should take no more than a hour to create (maybe two if you are new to programing) and you will learn some essential math skills required to write almost any type of game (BTW 3D vector math is almost identical to 2D with just the extra component called z).

---

#### To your problem

I have copied your code and made a few changes. I have also taken a few short cuts in the math described above. Like with any set of formulas if you put them all together you can simplify them to get a more effective and easy to understand formula. This is a particularly hand thing to do in games where you may be doing some calculations millions to 100's of millions of times a second.

The function `drawLineLength` takes the line segment x1,y1,x2,y2 and the value maxLen to draw a line that is no longer than `maxLen` pixels long.

If you have question please do ask in the comments.

#### Your code adjusted as to your question.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
c.lineWidth = 4;
c.lineCap = "round";
var turret = {x:20, y:20, w:20, h:20};
const maxLineLength = 50; // max length of line in pixels
var rBox = {              // FKA randomBox
     x : 0,
     y : 0, 
     w : 40, 
     h : 40
};

// drawLineLength  draws a line with maximum length
// x1,y1 from
// x2,y2  line to
// maxLen the maximum length of the line. If line is shorter it will not be changed
function drawLineLength (x1, y1, x2, y2, maxLen) {
    var vx = x2 - x1; // get dist between start and end of line
    var vy = y2 - y1; // for x and y

    // use pythagoras to get line total length
    var mag = Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy); 
    if (mag > maxLen) { // is the line longer than needed?

        // calculate how much to scale the line to get the correct distance
        mag = maxLen / mag;
        vx *= mag;
        vy *= mag; 
    }
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(x1, y1);
    c.lineTo(x1 + vx, y1 + vy);
    c.stroke();
}
// Test function is on a timer and run every 500ms (1/2 second)
function doTest () {
    // clear the canvas of last render
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // find a random position for the box inside the canvas and 10 pixels from any edge
    rBox.x = 10 + Math.random() * (canvas.width - rBox.w - 20);
    rBox.y = 10 + Math.random() * (canvas.height - rBox.h - 20); 
   
    // draw both objects
    c.fillStyle = "red";
    c.fillRect(turret.x, turret.y, turret.w, turret.h);

    c.fillStyle = "yellow";
    c.fillRect(rBox.x, rBox.y, rBox.w, rBox.h);

    // call function to draw line that will have a maximum length
    drawLineLength(
        turret.x + turret.w / 2, 
        turret.y + turret.h / 2,
        rBox.x + rBox.w / 2,
        rBox.y + rBox.h / 2,
        maxLineLength
    );
    setTimeout(doTest,500);
}
doTest();
```

```css
#canvas { background-color: #eee;  }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=500></canvas>
```

Comment: no need of doing this,just 
add original length and height.

Comment: @AkshayTilekar I think you may have miss read the question. The OP wants the line to stop at a specified distance from the red box, not from the corner of the red box to the yellow box. Well that is how I read it.

Comment: he want the line to stay within the boundaries of the turret,thats all

Comment: @Blindman67 I apologize for such a late comment, I was unable to get on this site yesterday. But yes this is what I'm looking for! And to make the line stay inside the box and not have any excess come out, would I just shorten the scale for the vector?

Comment: @CoderJS Yes. You would set the maxLen argument to half the box width or height whichever is shorter

Comment: @Blindman67 Thanks so much for such an in-depth answer. But I have one last question, if I do make a 2d vector library, what all should it cover? Can you think of a specific website or some details for me to cover in it?

Comment: @CoderJS you can just start with the basic operations and add to it as you go. You just need vector add(vec), subtract(vec), multiply(number), divide(number), getLength(), normalise() and that will cover most of your needs. You may also want clone() that creates a copy of the vector. It may also be some use to watch a youtube video on vector math and you can also have a look inside an existing lib to see how they do it. Top of the search results I found http://victorjs.org/ I dont know how good it is but worth having a look to see how they do it.